# Magento invoice get shipping address

Tags: php, magento

I want to show the shipping address of an order on my invoices. This is working pretty well with:

```
$shipping = nl2br($order->getShippingAddress()->format('html'));
$shipping = explode('<br />',$shipping);
```

But if I have an order for a download product (gift card) I get a:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function format()...

Because the order does not have a shipping address. How can I check, whether
`$order->getShippingAddress()` contains any data or, if not, not displaying it?

Comment: try [this](http://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/)

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. Made it like this:
  `if (empty($order->getShippingAddress())) {
            $ship_flag = 0;
  } else {
   $ship_flag = 1;
   $shipping = nl2br($order->getShippingAddress()->format('html'));
   $shipping = explode('<br />',$shipping);
  }`